# Trying to add value to a string and it keeps adding 1 over everytime

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am creating an online ticket booking system for my uni coursework, and I want to be able to display when a user has added a ticket to the cart on click, which would add the value of the ticket to the subtotal on each click capped at 3 tickets via an if statement. I can get it working when i use golfTotal but for some reason when I attempt to add it to the subtotal is doesnt register on the first click, but it works on the second, third and fourth click.

Ive tried setting it up so when the button is clicked it doesn't go through the if statement, rather just changing the total and adding to it each click. Unsure of what else I could try.

```
<div class="golf">
    <p id="golfTotalTickets">0</p>
    <p id="golfTotal"></p>
    <p><button onclick="golfAdd();" id="golfAdd">Add to Cart</button></p>
</div>                          

<div class="subtotal">
<div class="subtotal_text">
<h3 id="subtotal">Subtotal: £ <h3 id="total"> 
0.00</h3></h3><br>
</div>
```

```
var total = 0;
var golfTotal = 0;
var golfTotalTickets = 0;

function golfAdd() {

    golfTotalTickets += 1;
    document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = total.toFixed(2);

    if (golfTotalTickets <= 1) {
    golfTotal = 15;
    total += 15;
    document.getElementById("golfTotalTickets").innerHTML = golfTotalTickets + " Ticket";
    document.getElementById("golfTotal").innerHTML = golfTotal.toFixed(2);
    } else if (golfTotalTickets == 2){
    golfTotal += 15
    total += 15
    document.getElementById("golfTotalTickets").innerHTML = golfTotalTickets + " Tickets";
    document.getElementById("golfTotal").innerHTML = golfTotal.toFixed(2);
    } else if (golfTotalTickets == 3){
    golfTotal += 15
    total += 15
    document.getElementById("golfTotalTickets").innerHTML = golfTotalTickets + " Tickets";
    document.getElementById("golfTotal").innerHTML = golfTotal.toFixed(2);
    }else{
            window.alert("You are not allowed to buy more than 3 tickets for The Open.");
    }
}
```

When the button is clicked, the value of the sub total should be increased by 15 each click, except when golfTotalTickets hits 3 it should cap at 45.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can move the following `document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = total.toFixed(2);` to after the calculation. The reason being your calculation wasn't done yet before your `if-else`.

See snippet:

```js
var total = 0;
var golfTotal = 0;
var golfTotalTickets = 0;

function golfAdd() {

    golfTotalTickets += 1;
    //document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = total.toFixed(2); //move from there to after if else

    if (golfTotalTickets <= 1) {
    golfTotal = 15;
    total += 15;
    document.getElementById("golfTotalTickets").innerHTML = golfTotalTickets + " Ticket";
    document.getElementById("golfTotal").innerHTML = golfTotal.toFixed(2);
    } else if (golfTotalTickets == 2){
    golfTotal += 15
    total += 15
    document.getElementById("golfTotalTickets").innerHTML = golfTotalTickets + " Tickets";
    document.getElementById("golfTotal").innerHTML = golfTotal.toFixed(2);
    } else if (golfTotalTickets == 3){
    golfTotal += 15
    total += 15
    document.getElementById("golfTotalTickets").innerHTML = golfTotalTickets + " Tickets";
    document.getElementById("golfTotal").innerHTML = golfTotal.toFixed(2);
    }else{
            window.alert("You are not allowed to buy more than 3 tickets for The Open.");
    }
    document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = total.toFixed(2); //here
}
```

```html
<div class="golf">
    <p id="golfTotalTickets">0</p>
    <p id="golfTotal"></p>
    <p><button onclick="golfAdd();" id="golfAdd">Add to Cart</button></p>
</div>                          

<div class="subtotal">
<div class="subtotal_text">
<h3 id="subtotal">Subtotal: £ <h3 id="total"> 
0.00</h3></h3><br>
</div>
```

Comment: Probably the quickest answer i've ever had, you've just saved my coursework! thanks so much dude.